# What does it mean: Packer docker builder does not support running on a Docker remote host?

Tags: docker, packer, windows-container

I found interesting sentence in PACKER docker builder docs: "does not support running on a Docker remote host".
https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/docker

I am wondering what does it exactly mean.

I am trying to run it in the DevOps pipelines with service connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you run docker commands in most cases your using the local docker engine on the machine were you are running the commands. However docker also supports using a remote host for docker. You can read more here https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-deploy-on-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-compose/.

An example might be

```bash
# we use the DOCKER_HOST environment variable scenario to target docker hosts, but the same can be achieved by passing the -H, –host argument to docker-compose.

$ cd hello-docker
$ DOCKER_HOST=“ssh://user@remotehost” docker-compose up -d
```

In this case we are telling docker to invoke the docker API on the remote machine instead of the local machine.

In the case of the packer docs its saying the builder needs to run on the same machine as the docker engine. I.E you cannot run the builder on machine1 and then invoke the docker commands to run on machine2 docker engine. Instead you must run the docker commands against the docker engine on the local machine that the packer builder is on.